# how to prevent ThreadedWebsocketManager (binance python api) from asyncio.exceptions.TimeoutError?

Tags: binance, binance-smart-chain, binance-api-client

this error happens every 10 min in my code , I just do not know how to keep the ThreadedWebsocketManager alive all the time .the document did not express it clearly 。
will you good guys tell me how to fix it .

Answer (score 2):

To future people like me who are looking for a solution like me. I struggled with this problem for 3 weeks. Here are my findings that might be useful to you.

The python-binance library will get stuck in an infinite loop when there's asyncio.exceptions.TimeoutError error or any other errors related to socket connections to binance servers.

Please check the "socket_listener" and "_start_async_socket" methods in the "python-binance" library to find out more.

I came up with one solution and one work around.

**1- Change the python-binance source code:**

If you have the time and energy to modify the source code so it doesn't get stuck in infinite loops and recommend it as a good solution to the python-binance developers, then everybody will be happy. Not sure if the infinite loops were designed intentionally or not though.

Disadvantage:

- You're gonna have to burden the responsibility of managing another in-house modified package
- Your code might end-up with some other errors.

So be careful about the first solution.

**2- Run all your trading code in a multiprocessing.Process process**

It's actually a workaround and not a solution.

Change all your code in a way so all the trading activities get executed in a process. Then, define a status flag for each process and check the status constantly. If you notice something weird, you can terminate the process and restart it again. Here's an example:

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager


def start_trading():

    while True:

        with Manager() as manager:

            trader_info = manager.dict()
            trader_info["status"] = "idle"

            trader = Process(
                target = start_trader,
                args = (
                    your_args_here,
                    trader_info,)
                )

            trader.start()

        while True:
            current_status = trader_info["status"]
            last_time_status_changed = time.time()

            while True:
                if current_status != trader_info["status"]:
                    last_time_status_changed = time.time()
                    current_status = trader_info["status"]

                # If the status didn't change for 30 seconds
                if time.time() - last_time_status_changed > 30:
                    break

            trader.kill()
            trader.join()
            break

def start_trader(your_args_here, trader_info):

    while True:

        trader_info['status'] = 'checking_prices'
        price_info = check_prices()

        trader_info['status'] = 'checking_open_trade_conditions'
        should_open_trade = check_if_trade_needs_to_be_opened()

        trader_info['status'] = 'placing_order'
        order_result = place_order()

        time.sleep(60)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_trading()
```

If you use the above idea, you will see the timeout error and other errors. The code will also get stuck in the infinite loops of the python-binance. But it will restart the process if the status of the trader doesn't change after a while.

**IMPORTANT:**

1- The above code is just to give the idea. It's sub-optimal and not functional. Don't use it for any other purposes.

2- In production, you might end up having multiple processes and shared resources. Terminating a process in such cases will lead to BrokenPipeError. You must be careful with that problem.

3- This approach neglects ALL EXCEPTIONS and internal bugs. It works, but you might end up having a code that is absolutely wrong. Make sure you log all the exceptions and errors to manage them properly.

Answer (score -1):

I have the same issue here. It would be of great help if someone could provide a solution to this problem.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 351, in <module>
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "test.py", line 257, in main
    await asyncio.gather(
  File "test.py", line 208, in calculate
    second_pair_usdt = await client.get_symbol_ticker(symbol=second_token+FIAT_USD)
  File "C:\Users\Thoma\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\binance\client.py", line 6836, in get_symbol_ticker
    return await self._get('ticker/price', data=params, version=self.PRIVATE_API_VERSION)
  File "C:\Users\Thoma\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\binance\client.py", line 6551, in _get
    return await self._request_api('get', path, signed, version, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Thoma\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\binance\client.py", line 6514, in _request_api
    return await self._request(method, uri, signed, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Thoma\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\binance\client.py", line 6495, in _request
    async with getattr(self.session, method)(uri, **kwargs) as response:
  File "C:\Users\Thoma\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 1117, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro
  File "C:\Users\Thoma\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 619, in _request
    break
  File "C:\Users\Thoma\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\aiohttp\helpers.py", line 656, in __exit__
    raise asyncio.TimeoutError from None
asyncio.exceptions.TimeoutError
```